# How to add python libraries in CDAP python transformation?

Tags: python, cdap

I am creating a pipeline with the Python transformation process there I want to add the python libraries in CDAP pipeline. But its supporting only the OS and Date time libraries.

Answer (score 1):

As of 5.1 release the python transform uses Jython. [Improvement to Python](https://wiki.cask.co/display/CE/Python+transform+improvements) transform is in the works that would allow you to include any libraries. This will be part of 6.0 release that is likely to be released in Q2' 2019.